# #1932 table 'tablename' doesn't exist in engine

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this problem with an table. i want to delete it and does not work

I tried to delete de .ibd file, them rename some frm file to the same name as te ibd to drop the table , does not work

when i drop table, and then create it again, it gives me this error #1813 table space for table name still exist, please discart tablespace before import. and if i try ti discard, says that nametable does not exist

I even tried to alter the table

I`m using xampp

does anyone knwo how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried the Drop Table command?

Comment: Don't delete files. Don't rename files. Log into your server and delete the tables properly. `DELETE TABLE yourtablename;` There's almost never a good reason to monkey around in the file system with a database unless something is corrupt.

Comment: i tried to drop the table

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I solve this with: **DROP TABLE IF EXISTS yourtablename, yourtablename, yourtablename;** and reload the db backup.

I use XAMPP in Osx,You can also see logs:
tail /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/yourFile.local.err

You can also remove .ibd, I use XAMPP:
[image: command in MacOsx with XAMPP]

You should now work with your backup.